# grep: Keeping lines that has specific string in certain column

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to pick out the lines that have certain value in certain column and save it to an output. I am trying to do this with grep. Is it possible?

My data is looks like this:

```
apple   5   abcdefd  ewdsf
peach   5   ewtdsfe  wtesdf
melon   1   ewtedf   wersdf
orange  3   qqqwetr  hredfg
```

I want to pick out lines that have value 5 on its 2nd column and save it to new outputfile.

```
apple   5   abcdefd  ewdsf
peach   5   ewtdsfe  wtesdf
```

I would appreciate for help!

Answer (score 7):

It is probably possible with `grep` but the adequate tool to perform this operation is definitely `awk`.  You can filter every line having 5 on the second column with

```
awk '$2 == 5'
```

### Explanation

`awk` splits it inputs in records (usually a line) and fields (usually a column) and perform actions on records matching certain conditions. Here

```
awk '$2 == 5'
```

is a short form for

```
awk '$2 == 5 {print($0)}'
```

which translates to

```
For each record, if the second field ($2) is 5, print the full record ($0).
```

### Variations

If you need to choose dynamically the key value used to filter your values, use the `-v` option of `awk`:

```
awk -v "key=5" '$2 == key {print($0)}'
```

If you need to keep the first line of the file because it contains a header to the table, use the `NR` variable that keeps track of the ordinal number of the current record:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $2 == 5'
```

The *field separator* is a regular expression defining which text separates columns, it can be modified with the `-F` field.  For instance, if your data were in a basic CSV file, the filter would be

```
awk -F", *" '$2 == 5'
```

Visit the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag wiki to find a few useful information to get started learning `awk`.

Comment: If input table would have a header line, how do we preserve it?

Answer (score 4):

To print when the second field is `5` use: `awk '$2==5' file`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
grep '^[^\s]\+\s5.*$' file.txt
```

the pattern looks for start of line, followed by more than one non-space character, followed by space, followed by 5, follwed by any number of chars, followed by eol.

Comment: The `.*$` part is useless.

Comment: You never expect the Spanish Inquisition! ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can get following command.

```
$ cat data.txt
apple   5   abcdefd  ewdsf
peach   5   ewtdsfe  wtesdf
melon   1   ewtedf   wersdf
orange  3   qqqwetr  hredfg
grape   55  kkkkkkk  aaaaaa

$ grep -E '[^ ]+ +5 .*' data.txt > output.txt

$ cat output.txt
apple   5   abcdefd  ewdsf
peach   5   ewtdsfe  wtesdf
```

You can get the answer only with `grep` command.
But I strongly recommend you use `awk` command.

Answer (score -2):

The simple way to do it is:

```
grep '5' MyDataFile
```

The result:

```
apple   5   abcdefd  ewdsf
peach   5   ewtdsfe  wtesdf
```

To capture that in a new file:

```
grep '5' MyDataFile > newfile
```

**Note:** that will find a 5 anywhere in MyDataFile. To restrict to the second column, a short script is what would suit your needs. If you want to limit it to the second column only, then a quick script like the following will do. Usage: `script number datafile`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r fruit num stuff || [ -n "$stuff" ]; do
    [ "$num" -eq "$1" ] && printf "%s  %s  %s\n" "$fruit" "$num" "$stuff"
done <"$2"
```

**output:**

```
$ ./fruit.sh 5 dat/mydata.dat

apple  5  abcdefd  ewdsf
peach  5  ewtdsfe  wtesdf
```

Comment: I'm looking to restrict it to the second column. Sorry, the example I posted was bad. There are numeric values in other columns.